# Wi-Fi radio with an API

Tags: wifi, audio

I have several WiFi radios (Logitech, Ocen Digital) but all of them lack the ability to configure them programmatically.

I am looking for a WiFi radio (the simplest, the better) that would **allow for an HTTP-based configuration**:

- switching it on /off (a must)
- ability to select a station/stream as (a nice to have)

The ideal situation would be where the configuration is done directly n the radio, but accessing a cloud "command center" is fine too.

Comment: I'd look at your OS APIs and write a demon to forward it through.

Comment: Another thought is scripting the admin panel of a router which functions as a WiFi client.